# Is it no longer possible to publish to an offline user? Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am setting up a website that I would like to set up a script to automatically post to the users Facebook feed. Is this not possible anymore? Here's what I'm trying to accomplish.

1. User would come to my website. They would connect to Facebook and allow the "publish_actions" permission. They create a page on my site to receive donations.
2. I get an extended long lived access token.
3. User leaves my website.
4. Visitor comes to and donates to that user.
5. a post get's published to the user's page that they received the donation.

how could I edit this code for it to work if it's possible?

```
$response = (new FacebookRequest(NULL, 'POST', '/user_id/feed', array(
                  'message' => 'testing',
                  'access_token' => 'stored_longterm_access_token'
                )
              ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

Comment: In what way is it not currently working?

Comment: autoposting is not allowed, because that would be spam. also, prefilling the message is not allowed, it always must be 100% user generated. what you want to achieve is spam by definition, it´s not a "user message" (and that´s what it should be), it´s just a notification that´s only interesting for the user and not all his friends. just send an email to him.

Comment: Ahh ok, but this was possible in the past correct?

Comment: Yes, it was possible before v2.0.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Facebook Platform Policy Section 2.1](https://developers.facebook.com/policy#control) you must obtain consent from people before publishing content on their behalf. Even after a user gives your application permission to post your application must still provide a means for that user to approve the post via an explicit share button.

Additionally pre-filling a shared message is not allowed as well so ensure you are just sharing an open graph object and allowing your users to provide the context of the message that will be shared.